# Generate Javascript in MVC view file, but editor treats it as HTML file type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor

I want to deliver dynamically generated Javascript or JSON files in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in VS 2010.  I do this by returning `PartialView("somescript.js")` in the action method.  I then create the file `\Views\MyController\somescript.js.cshtml` containing the Javascript.  I'm also careful to set the `Response.ContentType` appropriately.

This seems to work fine from the browser.  However, VS 2010 treats editing `somescript.js.cshtml` as an HTML file, naturally.  This doesn't prevent me from editing the code, but I don't get the syntax highlighting and basic intellisense I would if I were editing a `.js` file.

Is there a way to tell VS or Razor to edit as Javascript on a per-file basis?

Comment: The most easiest way to get proper syntax highlighting is just to use <script> tags. To set VS behavior per file basis, well even if this is possible, I do not think it as a elegant solution.

Comment: Or perhaps I'm approaching this wrong.  If I could keep the .js file extension and still have it templated with Razor?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have Script Editor option in Open With dialog, Add `cshtml` extension in registry and you will able to open cshtml files with Script Editor

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Editors\{A52A054C-5228-4819-B568-E5B8040801B5}\Extensions
```

[image]

[image]